# Texture Not updating after being rendered once

Tags: canvas, three.js

I am trying to create a mouse tooltip following the example given in [1]. But the texture does not seem to update after first time it is rendered. I am using r73 and the example used r60. I can't seem to get a similar code working maybe there was a change between the revisions.

I have attached the code below. drawLabel creates the elements. I am trying to update the text of the tooltip as the mouse moves. On the mouse move event i try to update the text of the canvas but it does not update. i only get the tooltip as "0" (which count is initialized to). Am i missing something or was there some change in r73.  I have been trying to figure this out for days with no luck :(.

```
function drawLabel(){
// create a canvas element
canvas1 = document.createElement('canvas');
context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
context1.font = "Bold 20px Arial";
context1.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.95)";
context1.fillText('x', 0, 20);

// canvas contents will be used for a texture
texture1 = new THREE.Texture(canvas1)
////////////////////////////////////////

var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: texture1 } )  ;

sprite1 = new THREE.Sprite( spriteMaterial );
sprite1.scale.set(1,1,1);
sprite1.position.set( 0.05, 0.3,-0.12 );
scene3d.add(sprite1);
}

function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
// update sprite position
sprite1.position.set( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.2 );
context1.clearRect(0,0,640,480);
context1.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.95)"; // black border
context1.fillRect( 0,0,88,20+8);
context1.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,0.95)"; // white filler
context1.fillRect( 2,2, 94,20+4 );
context1.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)"; // text color
context1.fillText(count, 4,20 );
count = count + 1;
texture1.needsUpdate = true;
// update the mouse variable
mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
renderer.render( scene3d, camera );
```

}

[1] http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Mouse-Tooltip.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the problem. It seems this functionality is broken in r73. I updated my revision to r74 and it started to work.Adding an answer for everyone else's reference.